# Best way to monitor for a large (50000+) number of regions

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to create an app which does a specific action when the user enters a certain area.

Since the regions I want to monitor reside server-side (approx. 50.000 locations) and the number of regions is far too large to be registered for monitoring all at once, I want to start monitoring for regions which are close to the current location of the user.

To accomplish this I am thinking about using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`
to monitor whether the user has changed location and then use `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`
to register new regions to monitor and unregister regions which are now too far away.

My questions:

- Am I allowed do a call to a
  web-service in
  `didUpdateToLocation` while the app is
  in the background?
- Is this the best way to implement this kind of functionality or do you
  know of a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: check out my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297995/add-more-than-20-regions-to-geofencing-ios/24080059#24080059

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a space-filling-curve for example a z-curve of a hilbert-curve. It reduce the 2D problem to a 1D problem but it's most likely not answering your question.