# Add more than 20 regions to geofencing ios

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, geolocation, geofencing

I want to add 100 of regions to geofencing.(apple limit it to 20)any one have better idea for it.please help me.

currently im using significant location change.when significant location change,

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

method i call API with current location and get the nearest region set and add into geofencing.This method works.But i heard from web significant location change fire depend on the cell towers.If there less cell towers then it will be problem.Other thing is when calling api in background it will be effect to the battery.

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/14232712/22146